# How to calculate pixel location of object in 3D world

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have developed a 3d game and I have a box object off in the distance on a hill and I want to calculate the on screen pixel location for each of the four corners of the box so I can put an overlay on it.

The viewport is x1 magnification with a field of view of 45 degrees horizontal and 30 degrees vertical and the screen is 1280x1024 pixels.

Any idea on how to go about calculating this?

Comment: Look at rasterization.

Comment: I took a look and cannot see how this helps me calculate the X and Y pixel locations of an object in the distance

Comment: This is quite a commonly done thing and is covered in any computer graphics course. You might want to check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwDQ1_pXCLk